# What is the ABCD matrix of an impedance step?

Tags: microwave, network

What is the ABCD matrix of the following configuration, where a transmission line with characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$ is connected to another line with characteristic impedance \$Z_1\$ (if we consider \$Z_0\$ as port 1 and \$Z_1\$ as port 2)?

[image]

The \$S\$ matrix given in [this reference](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.82.1155) is

$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{Z_1 - Z_0}{Z_1 + Z_0} & \frac{2\sqrt{Z_0Z_1}}{Z_0 + Z_1}\\
\frac{2\sqrt{Z_0Z_1}}{Z_0 + Z_1} & \frac{Z_0 - Z_1}{Z_0 + Z_1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$

which I converted to the ABCD matrix as

$$
\text{ABCD} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{Z_1/Z_0} & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{Z_0/Z_1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

by the formulas from for example [here](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/abcd-matrix-vs-s-matrix.html). I wonder if there is a way to see the form of the ABCD matrix directly.

Comment: Where are you wanting to measure the impedance and what does this actually mean: "*There is no further electrical length on either side*" - please be clearer.

Comment: The questioner has obviously an idea: He uses ABCD presentations for chained parts and calculates the total effect as a matrix product. Only the ABCD matrix of one element is missing: That part is the zero length piece of transmission line which has only an impedance step. He already has ABCD matrices for parts in both sides of the step.

Comment: The ABCD matrix of the junction is just a 2x2 unit matrix [[1, 0], [0, 1]]. The formula you have used to convert between ABCD and S-parameters is only valid when the reference impedances on both ports are the same (i.e. Z1=Z0), which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

The ABCD matrix is defined by the equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}V_1\\I_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V_2\\-I_2\end{bmatrix}$$

What equations apply at infinitesimal point of transition between transmission lines with different characteristic impedance?

$$V_1 = V_2$$
$$I_1 = -I_2$$

So now all you have to do is work out what values of \$A\$, \$B\$, \$C\$ and \$D\$ make the ABCD equation match the equation for your network.

Comment: If \$V_1 = V_2\$, \$I_1 = -I_2\$, isn't the ABCD matrix just the identity matrix? But I think the answer should be $$\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{Z_1/Z_0} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{Z_0/Z_1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How is KCL satisfied in that case?

Comment: Actually I think the answer should be $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & Z_0 / Z_1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ I am getting this answer by converting the \$S\$ matrix shown in the reference to the ABCD matrix.

Comment: That's exactly where I'm confused about. I understand that by KCL \$I_1 = -I_2\$ should hold. But if \$V_1 = V_2, I_1 = -I_2\$, doesn't it imply both sides have the same impedance, which is not necessarily the case?

Comment: Because the thing you're characterizing with this ABCD matrix is not the transmission lines, but the connection between them. Which is essentially just an ideal wire in circuit theory terms.

Comment: Also, you said, "the S matrix shown in the reference", but you haven't named any reference. What reference are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to Eqs. (C51) to C(53) in the supplemental material of this paper https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.82.1155

Comment: Sorry, access to that material appears to be paywalled. You should add enough information to your question post to make it clear what you're asking.